Use PrimeFaces PF widget selector with classes
I've looked at the Primefaces selector for the "update" tag here: How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?
I was wondering if there was something similar for the PF function selector.
If I have multiple Primefaces panels I'd like to call .toggle() on, can I do it without referencing their individual widgetVars? Either through class or some other property I can lump them together.
For example:
    <script>
        function enableEditing() {
            try {
                PF( 'pnlTest1' ).toggle(); // works
                PF( 'pnlTest2' ).toggle(); // works

                PF( '@(.pnlTestClass' ).toggle(); // Can it work like this to toggle all panels?
            } catch ( e ) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <p:panel toggleable="true" closable="true" widgetVar="pnlTest1" styleClass="pnlTestClass" >
        Panel 1
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel toggleable="true" closable="true" widgetVar="pnlTest2" styleClass="pnlTestClass" >
        Panel 2
    </p:panel>


You can't do that with PF but here is some JS you can use
// find all panel widgets on the page
const panels = PrimeFaces.getWidgetsByType(PrimeFaces.widget.Panel);

// loop over them and if they match some criteria you care about 
for (let panel of panels) {
    if (panel.cfg.toggleable) {
        panel.toggle();
    }
}

